# Adding a lemma for a new word and the concept of normalization/lemmatization in spaCy

Tags: nlp, spacy, lemmatization

Following the examples from documentation regarding tokenization I have the following code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH, NORM

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
special_case = [{ORTH: "gim", NORM: "give"}, {ORTH: "me"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("gimme", special_case)

doc = nlp("gimme that. he gave me that. Going to someplace.")
```

Then I check the tokenization

```
doc[0].norm_  # 'give'  (as expected)
```

But the lemmatizer does not return the same output

```
lemmatizer = nlp.get_pipe("lemmatizer")
lemmatizer.lemmatize(doc[0])  # ['gim']  (expected ['give']
```

In other hand

```
lemmatizer.lemmatize(doc[5]) # ['give']
lemmatizer.lemmatize(doc[9]) # [go']
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to "fix"?  In spaCy what is the difference between **normalized** tokens and **lemmatized** tokens? How can I "teach" the lemmatization of a single token  (as this `gim` token in example) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you've customized the tokenizer to handle the special case "gimme" and normalize it to "give.

Here's how you can achieve consistent lemmatization results with your custom normalization

```py
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.symbols import ORTH, NORM
        
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
special_case = [{ORTH: "gim", NORM: "give"}, {ORTH: "me"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("gimme", special_case)
        
# Define a custom lemmatization function
@Language.component(name="custom_lemmatizer")
def custom_lemmatizer_function(doc):
    for token in doc:
        if token.norm_ == "give":
            token.lemma_ = "give"
    # Add more custom rules for other words if needed
    return doc
        
# Add the custom lemmatizer to the pipeline
nlp.add_pipe("custom_lemmatizer", name="custom_lemmatizer", after="lemmatizer")
        
doc = nlp("gimme that. he gave me that. Going to someplace.")
print(doc[0].lemma_)  # 'give' (as expected)
print(doc[5].lemma_)  # 'give' (as expected)
print(doc[9].lemma_)  # 'go' (as expected)
```

Comment: There isn't a better method or function to pass a dictionary of special cases to lemmatizer? otherwise this will be painfully slow in complex cases in a large dataset.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, in stable version of spacy (3.6.1) this approach do not works. Since is missing the `Language.component` decorator and the first parameter in `nlp.add_pipe` is a string (the name of registered component). Fixing these two issues. The code runs nicely.

Answer (score -1):

```
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.symbols import ORTH, NORM

# Load the spaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Define a special case to recognize "gimme" as "give me"
special_case = [{ORTH: "gim", NORM: "give"}, {ORTH: "me"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("gimme", special_case)

# Define a custom lemmatization function
@Language.component(name="custom_lemmatizer")
def custom_lemmatizer_function(doc):
    for token in doc:
        # Check if the normalized form of the token is "give"
        if token.norm_ == "give":
            # Override the lemma to "give"
            token.lemma_ = "give"
    # Add more custom rules for other words if needed
    return doc

# Add the custom lemmatizer to the pipeline after the default lemmatizer
nlp.add_pipe("custom_lemmatizer", name="custom_lemmatizer", after="lemmatizer")

# Process a text with the spaCy pipeline
doc = nlp("gimme that. he gave me that. Going to someplace.")

# Check lemmatization results`enter code here`
print(doc[0].lemma_)  # 'give' (as expected)
print(doc[5].lemma_)  # 'give' (as expected)
print(doc[9].lemma_)  # 'go' (as expected)
```